Relationship between references, variables and identities
I couldn't find definitions for the terms "reference", "variable" and "identity" in the Python glossary or in my textbook. I would like to clarify my understanding of these terms. Let's say we have an object obj. Is it true that the following phrases are synonyms in CPython:

"reference to obj", "identity of obj", "memory address of obj"  ?
"variable", "named reference", "identifier that is bound to some reference" ?
"variable a that refers to obj", "a pair consisting of identifier a, identity of obj" ?


P.S. Mark Lutz in his book "Learning Python" (5th ed.) says the following on p.177:

Readers with a background in C may find Python references similar to C pointers (memory addresses). In fact, references are implemented as pointers (in CPython), and they often serve the same roles, especially with objects that can be changed in place (more on this later). However, because references are always automatically dereferenced when used, you can never actually do anything useful with a reference itself; this is a feature that eliminates a vast category of C bugs. But you can think of Python references as C “void*” pointers, which are automatically followed whenever used.

Using this information and the answers below, I came up with my current understanding, which is as follows:
I. All expressions in Python (or, at least, most of them) return reference to an object.
II. In general, Python doesn't specify the internal structure of a reference. But in the CPython implementation references are implemented as C objects (PyObject* pointers), that are very similar to void* pointers, which are automatically followed whenever used. Such a reference is not a Python object, but it contains the actual memory address of a "PyObject C struct" that corresponds to some Python object. I think that this memory address is equal to the identity of that Python object (this is how reference and identity are connected in CPython).
III. A Python variable is an identifier that is bound to a reference, i.e. the following phrases are equivalent (obj is a Python object): "variable a that refers to obj" and "a pair consisting of identifier a, reference to obj". Variable is not a Python object because reference is not a Python object. Note that not all references are variables in Python.
IV. At the beginning of this post point 1 is partially false because "reference to obj" is not the same as "identity of obj" (in CPython a reference is a C pointer whereas identity is just an integer number). Point 2 is true. Point 3 is false (see the correct variant in p.III above).

It depends on the specific context. You're mixing up general language concepts and the way they're implemented.

Python doesn't usually use the term "reference", there are no true references as in c++.

@STerliakov I can just say that some important official documentation pages use this term. For example, this page: "A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original."

@Kambal well, there's a concept of reference as in "reference count" and weakref module (related to reference counting), and this clearly isn't synonymous to memory address.

See: Facts and myths about Python names and values.

A variable is a name (i.e., an identifier) that refers to a value.
A reference is any thing we can use to gain access to a value. References are generally produced by expressions, which can include, for example,

Literals (5, 'x', etc)
Variables (x)
List, dict, and set displays (including list and dict comprehensions)
Indexing operations (x[5])
Operator expressions (x and y, x + y)
Function calls (f(x))

"Identity" gets used in two related ways.

The identity of an object is an implementation-dependent integer associated with that object while it exists. You can use the id function to retrieve the identity given any reference to the object. (id(3), id(x), id(x[4), id(y + 3*z), etc)

We say two references are identical if they both refer to the same object, not just two objects that are equal. We can say with certainty that x is y is true after
x = 3
y = x

but not
x = 3242
y = 3242

because there is no guarantee that the same literal is always a reference to the same object. (Though in CPython, for example, small integers are interned. x = 3; y = 3; x is y will generally be true, but there is no guarantee that a more complex expression like x + 3* y is 5 will be true, even if x + 3 * y == 5.



Well, I have read that every value in Python is an object. If this is true, then we can say, "A reference is any thing we can use to gain access to an object." And now I can think of only one way to access an object - by using its identity (memory address), that's why I wrote that the terms "reference to obj" and "identity of obj" are synonymous. I am curious to see what other ways there are to gain access to an object.

You can't use the identity to access an object. It's only an implementation detail of CPython that the identity is a memory address. Python only guarantees that the identity is an integer that is unique to that object while the object exists, and defines no way to access memory directly.

Based on your useful answer, I corrected my understanding of the terms "reference", "identity", and "variable" and wrote it at the end of my opening post (as an edit). Please feel free to comment on it if it still contains some incorrect statements.

I think you're a bit confused so i will try to explain basics of them:
A Reference actually a point to the memory location of that object.
assume you have a mylist=[1,2,3,4] here is mylist is your object and it is reference to the list object in memory but it doesn't hold actual 1,2,3,4 data it only refers to that location let me breaking down for you:
when you create mylist=[1,2,3,4] python creates a new list object in memory that contains 1,2,3,4 this list is an object resides in a spesific location in your computers memory. if you say mylist2=mylist and mylist2.remove(4) then it would effect mylist too. Because they reference to same location but they don't hold data twice. Though this is only possible because list is a mutable object.
Variable "mylist": so that variable named mylist is actually a reference/pointer to that list object, it does not hold any data but it holds a pointer or a reference to the actual memory address.
Identity of object means unique identity of the object it's usually refers to the actual address of that object but that's not always the case while it is like this in cpython in other implementations of python this could be just a unique number for that object so it depends on which python you use.
Memory address of obj now you know in cpython this is equal to identity of  the object but not for other pythons.
Memory
|Ref:1 | Adress:0x00400000 | Value : [1,2,3,4]  | //The list object in memory
Variable
| mylist  |
| ref = 1 |  // points to the reference of the list
| mylist2  |
| ref = 1 |

Thanks. So, can we say that "reference to obj" in CPython is a C-pointer, i.e. this is a C-object that contains actual address (identity) of obj?

That's a good question! So underneath the hood implementation of Python already uses C pointers in order to manage object references but in the end "reference to obj" is a Python-specific concept; It serves as a kind of pointer that allows the access or manipulation of an object without directly dealing with the memory address.
But in C, a variable that holds the memory address of another variable is called a pointer. It allows direct access to and manipulation of the memory location where the data is actually stored. They're similar but not particularly same.
